# What would be the correct action if a question is no longer relevant?

Tags: support

I have this post on stackoverflow, which I've solved myself, but the answer is extremely stupid and I'd rather not share it. That means I don't require any more assistance on that question, but none of the answers on that post helped me in any way. Do I just leave the question as it is and not touch it, or should I delete the question? It doesn't really feel right to just leave the question that others might find but is complete useless.

EDIT: Link to the post if anyone wants it : 
[Why doesn't onActivityResult() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624138/why-doesnt-onactivityresult-work)

Comment: Do you dare to share a link to that question or can I pick a random question from your profile to decide?

Comment: @rene Well, I'll add the link to the post, but don't think it really matters :)

Comment: @Piofmc It can still be helpful to have an example.

Comment: But I don't see how you self answered that?

Comment: @rene oh woops, my bad, meant to say that I've solved myself

Comment: In that case I advice you to post your solution as an answer. Based on the comments the solution is not trivial.

Comment: @rene Well, I just feel that the answer is stupidly easy and simple that it's not really worth to have the question there, but sure, I'll post the answer and mark the answer.

Comment: Don't only go on my advice. I'm not an android dev...

Comment: @rene Android or not, it's a Q&A site. If you ask a Q, and you come up with an A on your own, stupid or not it's still an A -- and we like to have A's for all of our Q's. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your solution is from one of the answers there, accept the answer.

If your solution is different, then post it as an answer. It doesn't really matter if you think it is "stupid" -- if somebody else has a similar problem and it helps them, then it is good, and in any case posting your answer and accepting it will stop other potential answerers from also trying to diagnose the issue that you have already solved.

The community is capable of closing questions that aren't deemed useful in the long run, you don't have to be concerned with that part.

Comment: Thanks rene too for the comments